# Protect get_query_var from manual input in url

Tags: functions, urls

I have a custom rewrite rule for a page that filters images by tag.
All works well, except (and this is for want of a better word "malicious") direct input to url.
With a url of `mywebsite.com/discover/interiors/view/contemporary/kitchen/` `get_query_var('tag1')` will get the `contemporary` and `kitchen` and then proceed to filter by these, but..

If someone decided to alter the URL to `mywebsite.com/discover/interiors/view/?contemporary/kitchen/` the `get_query_var()` will break and return empty.

I've tried using `str_replace` to remove the `?` from the `get_query_var()` string but it fails, probably because get_query_var function doesnt get called.

Question is , how can I remove, replace the ? from the url and still keep the get_query_var string?

At the moment, I have a wp_redirect working if the get_query_var string is empty but would rather continue with the page by removing the ?

Answer (score 1):

When someone messes up an URL it's typically not something to *do* anything about. If you look at any site's log they receive tons of completely broken and malformed requests every day.

You only have to care about one case — that URL parses properly and input data is valid and safe.

Whenever request is outside of these conditions you just do nothing and allow it to fail as 404 error.

Comment: Rarst, appreciate your answer and your tidying up of the original question, but.
Although I fully understand your comment, if as in my case the adding of the ? causes a Fatal error: then it wont fail to a 404, it will show Fatal error:
I suppose you could comment that I havent written the code the best I could and should take into account that if get_query_var is empty then dont call the query, which effectively what I have done with the redirect back to parent page.
But I was just asking if anyone knew a way of overcoming the manual input and allowing the code to run as normal.

Comment: Code cannot run "as normal" for invalid input. Or other way around — handling invalid input without errors _is_ normal. There is infinite number of ways that URL can be changed and made invalid, you can't handle each and every one of them one by one.

Comment: Disagree, Code can run as normal after invalid input, if the invalid input is corrected prior to input meeting the function or part of code requiring it.
The reason I asked here is that get_query_var is a Wordpress function, if a ? is placed in front of the parameters it breaks, I can add anything else there and it runs fine (in my case), just not a ?.
No problem, I shall endevour to search good ole google deeper, thanks for taking the time to reply.